# How can I combine alpha and color in one legend

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a stacked bar graph where colors represent the category and I've adjusted the alpha to subdivide those into 2. 
The legend shows the alpha (in shades of grey) and the colors.
However I would like to make a legend that contains the combinations.

To combine them I've looked at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19330257/changing-the-color-in-the-legend-with-ggplot2-in-r) but I cannot combine the alpha and fill. 
Here is an reproducible figure that doesn't work:

```
mtcars %>% 
ggplot(aes(gear, mpg, fill = as.factor(vs), alpha = as.factor(am)))+
geom_bar(stat = "identity")+
scale_fill_manual(name = "legend",
                  values = c(
                      "0" = "red",
                      "1" = "blue",
                      "0"="red",
                      "1"="blue"
                      ),
                  labels = c("V-engine, automatic", 
                             "V-engine, manual",
                             "Straight-engine, automatic",
                             "Straight-engine, manual")
                  )+
scale_alpha_manual(name = "legend",
                   values = c(
                       "0" = 1,
                       "1"=2/5,
                       "0"=1,
                       "1"=2/5
                       ),
                   labels = c(
                       "V-engine, automatic", 
                       "V-engine, manual",
                       "Straight-engine, automatic",
                       "Straight-engine, manual"
                       )  )
```

[image]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I approached your question not using `aes(alpha)` but treating `alpha` as `fill.colour` with combination of `vs` and `am`.

```
mtcars %>% 
  ggplot(aes(gear, mpg, fill = interaction(as.factor(vs), as.factor(am)))) +
    geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
    scale_fill_manual(name = "legend",
                      values = c(
                          "0.0" = alpha("red", 1),
                          "1.0" = alpha("blue", 1),
                          "0.1" = alpha("red", 2/5),
                          "1.1" = alpha("blue", 2/5)
                          ),
                      labels = c("V-engine, automatic", 
                                 "V-engine, manual",
                                 "Straight-engine, automatic",
                                 "Straight-engine, manual")
                      )
```

[image]

Comment: This is ra eally great idea! I'll try and report back!

Comment: This is indeed a great idea. It works nicely with my data. Thanks!