# Show alpha/opacity in ggplot legend

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart, alpha, position-dodge

I have two dodge bar chart which I have put on top of each other to create this plot.

```
Groups <- c(1, 2,1,2,1,2)
variable <- c("Yes", "Yes", "Maybe", "Maybe", "No", "No")
value <- c(50,60,70,80,90,100)
df <- data.frame(Groups, variable, value)

Groups <- c(1, 2,1,2,1,2)
variable <- c("Yes*", "Yes*", "Maybe*", "Maybe*", "No*", "No*")
value <- c(5,6,7,8,9,10)
df2 <- data.frame(Groups, variable, value)

ggplot() +
  geom_bar(data=df, aes(x=Groups, y=value, fill=variable),
           stat="identity", position=position_dodge(), alpha=0.2)+
  geom_bar(data=df2, aes(x=Groups, y=value, fill=variable),
           stat="identity", position=position_dodge())
```

[image]

**I would like for the opacity/alpha from the plot behind to show in the legend.**

I have tried `+guides(colour = guide_legend(override.aes = list(alpha = 0.2)))` but this does not work.

Thanks.

Comment: combine the two data sets and use `alpha` as a mapping ...

Comment: See here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39249457/how-can-i-combine-alpha-and-color-in-one-legend

Answer (score 2):

You can use a little trick with `after_scale` to achieve this. Map `fill` to the `variable` in one geom layer, and map `color` to `variable` in the second layer, but set the second layer's `fill` to `after_scale(color)`. This will give you two legends, one for the first data set with its transparency, and the other for the second set, fully opaque. You can call these whatever you like using `labs`

```r
ggplot(df, aes(Groups, value)) +
  geom_col(aes(fill = variable), position = 'dodge', alpha = 0.2) +
  geom_col(data = df2, aes(color = variable, fill = after_scale(color)),
           position = 'dodge') +
  labs(color = 'df2', fill = 'df1')
```

[image]

If you want everything in a single legend, you can do this in a couple of ways, for example, using a manual fill value with 6 colors, 3 of which have alpha set, or just merging the two legends in the method above using theme tweaks:

```r
ggplot(df, aes(Groups, value)) +
  geom_col(aes(fill = variable), position = 'dodge', alpha = 0.2) +
  geom_col(data = df2, position = 'dodge', size = 0,
           aes(color = variable, fill = after_scale(color))) +
  labs(color = 'key', fill = NULL) +
  guides(fill = guide_legend(order = 2), 
         color = guide_legend(order = 1, 
                   override.aes = list(color = 'white', size = 0.3))) +
  theme(legend.spacing.y = unit(-2, 'mm'),
        legend.title = element_text(vjust = 5))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your help. I went with a simpler approach suggested by someone above. I did 
+
  scale_fill_manual(values=c("Maybe"= alpha("#7570b3", 0.2),"Maybe*"= alpha("#7570b3", 1),.......and so on... ))

Comment: @Alis - this is what I meant when I said above 'using a manual fill value with 6 colors, 3 of which have alpha set'