# Problems using ggplot labels

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a trouble by setting the legend colors on my plot, I just can not to set the appropriate colors on my legend and all three appear red: [Multiple Scatter ggplot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tksRK.png). I tried using `scale_colour_manual` options and `scale_fill_manual` but it does not work. I do not know if the data frame and the code in gerenarl are appropiated but it were the only way I found for putting different regression lines on the same plot.
Here is a MWE:

```
`library("ggplot2")
ConcCurve<-c(0.000,5.809,11.514,21.995,32.349,44.390,53.552)
ABSHei<-c(0.01299076, 0.44779044, 0.87251242, 1.64435113, 2.41385198, 3.25395864,3.93389333)
ABSAr3<-c(0.0224455, 0.8303167, 1.6170380, 3.0466451, 4.4496162, 5.9631238, 7.1746112)
ABSAr5<-c(0.03847996,  1.44915907,  2.81864550,  5.29479463,  7.69466231, 10.27269797, 12.32472597)
DataR<-data.frame(ConcCurve,ABSHei,ABSAr3,ABSAr5)
p1<-ggplot(DataR) + 
  geom_point(aes(x=ConcCurve,y=ABSHei,fill="Height"),colour="blue") + 
  geom_smooth(aes(ConcCurve,ABSHei), method="lm", se=T,level = 0.9999,lwd=0.6, col ="blue" ) +
  geom_point(aes(x=ConcCurve,y=ABSAr3,fill = "Area 3 pix"),colour="green") + 
  geom_smooth(aes(ConcCurve,ABSAr3), method="lm", se=T,level = 0.9999,lwd=0.6, col ="green" ) +
  geom_point(aes(x=ConcCurve,y=ABSAr5,fill = "Area5 pix"),colour="red")+ 
  geom_smooth(aes(ConcCurve,ABSAr5), method="lm", se=T,level = 0.9999,lwd=0.6, col ="red" ) +
  labs(x = expression(paste(plain("Hg"^plain("2+"))," Concentration (",mu,"g ",plain("kg"^plain("-1")),")")), y = "Integrated absorbance")+
  ggtitle("Calibration curves obtained using R")+ 
  guides(fill = guide_legend(reverse=F,title="Evaluation\nmode"))+
    scale_colour_manual(labels=c("Heigth", "Area 3 pix", "Area 5 pix"),
                        breaks=c("Heigth", "Area 3 pix", "Area 5 pix"),
                        values=c("blue","green","red"))
print(p1)
`
```

How can I configure the colors so they appear in the way that explain?

Comment: It seems there are some typos in your code (e.g. "Heigth"), though they don't seem to be the only cause of the problem, as fixing them doesn't yield your desired results.

Comment: I also tried solutions given in questions such as these, and they didn't work: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19330257/changing-the-color-in-the-legend-with-ggplot2-in-r

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ggplot syntax is more suited to long data format - if you reshape the data frame, it should solve the problem and make the code simpler. Like this:

```
library("ggplot2")
ConcCurve<-c(0.000,5.809,11.514,21.995,32.349,44.390,53.552)
ABSHei<-c(0.01299076, 0.44779044, 0.87251242, 1.64435113, 2.41385198, 3.25395864,3.93389333)
ABSAr3<-c(0.0224455, 0.8303167, 1.6170380, 3.0466451, 4.4496162, 5.9631238, 7.1746112)
ABSAr5<-c(0.03847996,  1.44915907,  2.81864550,  5.29479463,  7.69466231, 10.27269797, 12.32472597)
DataR<-data.frame(ConcCurve, ABS=c(ABSAr5,ABSAr3,ABSHei),
        mode=rep(c("Area 3 pix", "Area 5 pix", "Height"), each=7))

ggplot(DataR, aes(x=ConcCurve, y=ABS, color=mode)) + geom_point() +
    geom_smooth(method="lm", level=0.9999, lwd=0.6) +
    labs(x = expression(paste(plain("Hg"^plain("2+"))," Concentration (",mu,"g ",plain("kg"^plain("-1")),")")),
         y = "Integrated absorbance") +
    ggtitle("Calibration curves obtained using R") + 
    guides(guide_legend(title="Evaluation\nmode"))
```

All aesthetics were moved to main ggplot call. Then both `point` and `smooth` use the same grouping and colors (i.e. by the `mode` column) without writing it twice. Since we are using the inbuilt color scale, there is no need to explicitly specify any scales or colors for each group.
Note also that I reordered the ABS types when making the dataframe.

[image]

Comment: This is a very elegant solution, I also tried the dataframe reforming but at that time that does not worked. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution

```
ggplot(DataR) + 
  geom_point(aes(x=ConcCurve,y=ABSHei, color="blue")) + 
  geom_smooth(aes(ConcCurve,ABSHei), color="blue", method="lm", se=T,level = 0.9999,lwd=0.6) +
  geom_point(aes(x=ConcCurve,y=ABSAr3, color="green")) + 
  geom_smooth(aes(ConcCurve,ABSAr3), color ="green", method="lm", se=T,level = 0.9999,lwd=0.6 ) +
  geom_point(aes(x=ConcCurve,y=ABSAr5, colour="red"))+ 
  geom_smooth(aes(ConcCurve,ABSAr5), color ="red", method="lm", se=T,level = 0.9999,lwd=0.6 ) +
  labs(x = expression(paste(plain("Hg"^plain("2+"))," Concentration (",mu,"g ",plain("kg"^plain("-1")),")")), y = "Integrated absorbance")+
  ggtitle("Calibration curves obtained using R")+ 
  guides(color = guide_legend(reverse=F,title="Evaluation\nmode"))+
    scale_colour_identity(labels=c("Height", "Area 3 pix", "Area 5 pix"),
                        breaks=c("blue", "green", "red"), guide="legend")
```

Note that you weren't using a fill really so I got rid of those. I moved the color into the `aes()` to get a legend. Then I also used a `scale_color_identity` to use the literal color values and rename them in the legend via the `labels=` parameter.

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot, this were my first experience in stackoverflow and you appropriate answer solved my problem, leds me to learn a little bit about ggplot2 and to get rid of the stress that this was causing me, additionally in a very fast way. Thanks again :D

Comment: The answer from @juod  is a better long term solution. ggplot is much easier to use if your data is in a tidy format. Adding multiple layers like this should be avoided if possible.